# Exact definition of "Liveness" and "Safety" properties in a consensus?

Tags: security, consensus, terminology, safety

Two main properties of a consensus are "**Liveness**" and "**Safety**".

What are the exact and precised definition of "**Liveness**" and "**Safety**" properties in a consensus ?

Are the following definitions correct?

- **Safety:** Achieving an agreement on a single state by all participants ?
- **Liveness:** Possibility of updating this state with keeping the agreement ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liveness

Answer (score 4):

**Safety**: Any transaction deemed final by one properly-operating node will eventually be deemed final by every properly-operating node. No two transactions ever deemed final by two properly-operating nodes will ever conflict.

**Liveness**: So long as there is always at least one transaction suitable for inclusion that has not been deemed final by any properly-operating nodes, the set of transactions deemed final by at least one properly-operating node will increase in number.

Note that these are very, very minimal definitions and generally not sufficient for realistic systems. Also, for some systems (where a transaction can produce different results depending on the context in which it executes), you have to understand "transaction" to mean the results of executing the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Safety: never achieving agreement on a state when nodes have not actually agreed on that given state, provided the assumptions of the paper hold ([read the wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)).

Liveness: consensus cannot stall, even in case of a tie, algo must always make progress ([read the wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liveness)).